# Memory Size Errors When Running Magento's cron.sh

Tags: magento, cron

We have set the nginx user to run the following command at 5 minute intervals.

```
sh /var/www/magento/cron.sh
```

This was executed fairly successfully for some time. Within the last month or so, it has begun to error out each time due to memory limit. I've increased the memory limit but that's only caused a higher limit that gets reached. It seems that there must be a bigger problem. The error is consistently as follows.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php on line 589
```

Below are the crons that magento has set to run every five minutes:

```
job: xmlconnect_notification_send_all   
model: xmlconnect/observer::scheduledSend   
file: /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/etc/config.xml

job: newsletter_send_all    
model: newsletter/observer::scheduledSend   
file: /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/etc/config.xml

job: enterprise_staging_automates
model: enterprise_staging/observer::automates   
file: /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Enterprise/Staging/etc/config.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message has all the answers

> Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted

While 262144 bytes seems like a big number, it's only [256KB](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&espv=210&es_sm=91&q=262144+bytes+in+kilobytes&spell=1&sa=X&ei=iaCFUqeSAcTfyQGipYCIDg&ved=0CCkQvwUoAA&biw=1271&bih=617), or around [.25 MB](https://www.google.com/search?q=262144+bytes+in+megabytes&oq=262144+bytes+in+megabytes&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6819j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

I believe the Magento documents recommend a memory limit of 256MB, with 512MB being a far more common in the wild.  You'll need make sure your command PHP version (or the command line PHP launched by `cron.sh`) has it's [memory_limit ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) set correctly.  One common pitfall here is to omit the `M`, or to use `MB`

```
; Will not do what you want it to
memory_limit=256
memory_limit=256MB
```

So make sure your configuration file is set something like this

```
memory_limit=256M
```

Comment: Also note that there are several different php processors involved in running Magento. Currently, on several Linux distrubutions, you may have separate configurations for Command Line (cli), CGI (fastCGI), and Apache DSO module php interpreters. Most people run Apache DSO and cli. The Website frontend and backend use the DSO settings, scripts such as shell/*, cron.php run off of cli. You will find that setting memory_limit in .htaccess does not affect the cli php interpreter. Using phpinfo() invoked by each interpreter will help troubleshoot the memory limit failure. In this case nginx nix DSO

Comment: "I've increased the memory limit but that's only caused a higher limit that gets reached."

Comment: If your error is consistently "Allowed memory size of 262144", then you haven't upped the memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server setup issue. Your php CLI memory_limit is set too low.

Bounce it up to 256M.

If you're not running your own server, then you need to contact your hosting provider.